# How to add record to ExtJS store "persistently"?

Tags: javascript, extjs, crud

There are two stores with same model : *inputStore* and *outputStore*.
A grid in the *Concepts* panel display data from *inputStore*.
When the user checkboxes a row in that grid (via Ext.selection.Checkbox.Model), the record is added in the *outputStore*.

I've managed to do that but cannot add the record **persistently** to the *outputStore*. Here is how I did it :

I added a listener to the Ext.selection.Checkbox.Model that is a part of the grid:

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
listeners: {
    select: {
        fn: me.onCheckboxModelSelect,
        scope: me
    }
}
})
```

And then the record is added to *outputStore* which works fine.

```
onCheckboxModelSelect: function(rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {
    var griddd = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#outputGridPanel')[0];
    griddd.getStore().add(record);
}
```

I've tried *Store.sync()*, *Store.commitChanges()* and *Store.save()*.

Hi back! changed both stores from inline data stores to json stores with proxy. For example here is the *outputStore*:

```
Ext.define('justConcepts.store.outputStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'justConcepts.model.ConceptsModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'justConcepts.model.ConceptsModel',
        storeId: 'outputStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data/output.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'concepts'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

Here is the **data/output.json** file :

```
{
concepts: [
    {  
      "id": "00A212",  
      "name": "Pays",  
      "adjacencies": ["00A213", "01A455"]  
    },
    {  
      "id": "00A213",  
      "name": "Ville",  
      "adjacencies": ["00A212"]  
    },  
    {  
      "id": "01A455",  
      "name": "Fleuve", 
      "adjacencies": ["00A212"]  
    } 
]
}
```

*griddd.getStore().add(record);* is still working but cannot persist and *griddd.getStore().getProxy().getModel().save();* not working.

Comment: When you are saying persistently, I assume you mean it is being pushed over the wire into either a database or some sort of data store. 

Does this store have a proxy setup to handle saves?

Comment: just a store with inline data

Comment: Where are you expecting it to persist? It's a static json file.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Can't it write in that json file?

Comment: No, it can't. Can you imagine if you could just make a request to a server and have it update the file?

Comment: ok I see. I feel kinda dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be in the model definition.

Have you tried:

```
griddd.getStore().getProxy().getModel().save();
```

And by the way the method Ext.data.Store.save() does not exist. I mean, i think it was removed  from versions v4.x of ExtJs.

Example taken from [Sencha ExtJS Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory)

```
//this is the model we will be using in the store
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string', mapping: 'phoneNumber'}
    ]
});

//this data does not line up to our model fields - the phone field is called phoneNumber
var data = {
    users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Ed Spencer',
            phoneNumber: '555 1234'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Abe Elias',
            phoneNumber: '666 1234'
        }
    ]
};

//note how we set the 'root' in the reader to match the data structure above
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'User',
    data : data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

You have all the information in there. 
But if you need specific help, you should post all your code so that we can help you!

Comment: Do you have a model defined with a proxy, or are you just using a store with inline data?

Comment: **I've tried that now. The debugger returned this** _'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'griddd.getStore().getProxy().getModel().save()')_ **but save() is a method of Ext.data.Model! So maybe** _griddd.getStore().getProxy().getModel()_ **didn't return a model. I did :** `alert(griddd.getStore().getProxy().getModel());` **Here is what I got as JS alert :** _function j() {return this.constructor.apply(this,arguments)||null;}_

Comment: just a store with inline data

Comment: talking about persistence in case of inline data is irrelevant??

Comment: In your case yes, because you don't have a [Ext.data.proxy.Memory](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory)

If you create a model with a memory proxy (or a physical one) then you can actually save the records!

Comment: Ah ok! But I really want to be able to persist those records in the _outputStore_ Could you help please transform this _outputStore_  from an inline data store to the one you said? @Vu Nguyen